# "Everyone who's interested in" or "Everyone who has interest in"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs

I'm preparing a text for a website and can't figure out which of these phrases I should use:

> "This is the meeting point for everyone **who’s** interested in (...)"
>
> "This is the meeting point for everyone **who has** interest in (...)"

Which is correct?

Comment: _This is the meeting point for everyone interested in..._

Comment: The question's title doesn't match the question's content; "interest" is not a verb in the latter, but a noun.

Comment: The latter seems to me like it would be more natural with the indefinite article "an" before "interest". "...everyone who has *an* interest in..."

Comment: @Carlo_R It should be correct now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's second version is *not* standard English usage. Simplifying slightly...

> 1: *John is interested in baseball* (standard phrasing: John finds baseball interesting)
>    2: **John has interest in baseball* (completely unacceptable)
>    3: *John has an interest in baseball* (valid, but [relatively uncommon](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has%20an%20interest%20in,is%20interested%20in&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=))
>    4: *John has interests in baseball* (see note below)

Note - #4 is a completely different usage to #1, relating to [senses 2, 3, 4 here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interest) It would normally be understood as meaning John gains financial or other benefits from baseball. But #3 could be used with either of senses #1 or #4, so it's probably best avoided unless the context makes everything clear.